# Segue to new view controller within a nav bar, the memory keeps rising

Tags: ios, swift

I am learning and working on an ios app. I have a nav bar with buttons that are programmed to present other view controllers in the app. Heres a sample of the code:

```
let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: “ViewController”) as! ViewController
        
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

As I navigate around the app while running the simulation the Memory keeps rising. Should I be clearing previous pages viewed so that the memory doesn't rise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time when presenting a new scene in your app, you as a developer are responsible for **presenting** and **dismissing** the scene properly.

There are many ways of presenting a scene.

For example,The `push`-style navigation automatically contains/adds controls for `backward navigation` because it adds all ViewControllers to its `navigation stack`; all ViewControllers will be embedded in the same `NavigationController`; thus, when dismissing it, you have to write:

```
navigationController.popViewController(animated: true)
```

The VC will be **popped** (removing an element from the top of the stack, newest element in the stack) and not *just* dismissed.

In case of presenting scenes **modally**, these ViewControllers have to have their **own** `NavigationController`.
thus, when dismissing it, you have to write:

```
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Do you see the difference?
If dismissing is handled properly, then there *should* be no memory leak.
Presenting and dismissing is related to Navigation in your app, and every scene has this navigation "section" where you handle dismissing which prevents from memory leak.

Hope it can help you a little bit.